# GLOG saves to file only one, first message

Tags: c++, windows, logging, visual-studio-2012, glog

I'm using `glog` library, but I have problem with printing more than one message to file.

When I use this code:

```
std::string appPath = TUtil::ExePath() + "logs\\";
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_INFO, std::string(appPath + "INFO").c_str());
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_ERROR, "");
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_FATAL, "");
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_WARNING, "");

google::InitGoogleLogging("");

LOG(INFO) << "Info1";
LOG(INFO) << "Info2";
LOG(WARNING) << "Warning1";
LOG(ERROR) << "ERROR1";
//LOG(FATAL) << "FATAL1";
```

I'm getting this log file (you can see that it lacks in all messages except first one):

```
Log file created at: 2013/09/22 20:22:03
Running on machine: XXX
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0922 20:22:03.047548  9512 test.cpp:36] Info1
```

However, when I uncomment `LOG(FATAL)`, it prints all the messages:

```
Log file created at: 2013/09/22 20:39:52
Running on machine: XXX
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0922 20:39:52.060691 34104 test.cpp:36] Info1
I0922 20:39:52.063691 34104 test.cpp:37] Info2
W0922 20:39:52.063691 34104 test.cpp:38] Warning1
E0922 20:39:52.063691 34104 test.cpp:39] ERROR1
F0922 20:39:52.066692 34104 test.cpp:40] FATAL1
```

And I have completely no idea what may cause it. It's simple as that - when I print `fatal` log message, it (and everything before it) is printed to file. But when there's no `fatal` message, only the first one is printed.

Did anyone maybe encounter similar problem, or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As any asynchronous logger, it will flush only for priority messages, you must call `google::LogMessage::Flush()` to write all messages to the output.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for a simple and very quick answer... it solved my problem. By the way, where may I read more about it? I can see only this http://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html Is there anything more than that?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only doc available as far as I know, missing flush is a very common issue while using buffered I/O.

Answer (score 2):

FLAGS_logbufsecs = 0; solve the problem for me. But it may have some performance issues.
https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/issues/detail?id=52&can=1&q=flush